# jquery height/width behave different in FF / Chrome on template HTMLs

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, height, width

when I pass a template HTML string to jquery and try to get its height/width (the template is not yet in the DOM) then Firefox and Chrome behave different:

Firefox seems to be able to calculate the values (from css etc) and returns a "valid" value but Chrome just returns 0.

Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/5AWtF/21/

Is this a bug or do I have to put the template into the DOM first so the dimensions can be  guaranteed?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised it worked in FF, add it to the DOM and it should work for all browsers